# Changing device date ionic refresh not working

Tags: cordova, ionic2, ibm-mobilefirst

Using Ionic 2, Pull to refresh is working fine but for a specific scenario, if I change my mobile date to some other date and in the app, am not able to pull down to refresh the page.

Comment: Does refresh connect to server? What version of MFP server?

Comment: MFP 8.0, Yes the refresh has the Server calls but i couldnt pull down in the app also..

Comment: In device logs , do you see a message such as INVALID_JWT_FORMAT ?

Comment: I didnt see any error message also but it happens only for PAST date. If i change the future date in mobile, its working fine

Comment: check your error logs and attach with question plz.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because MFP server does not allow an authentication request ( for OAuth token) from the past. ie, if the client device is running time behind the MFP server, MFP server breaks the OAuth flow when the request for token reaches it. The time of the client device should be in sync with the MFP server or atleast ahead of it.